# Most Compatible Versions of Some React Native Libraries

Tags: react-native, version

## Hi

So, I want to know some best and most compatible versions of some *React Native* Libraries.

```
    "axios"
    "firebase"
    "expo-font"
    "expo-app-loading"
    "react-native-svg"
    "react-navigation"
    "@expo/vector-icons"
    "react-native-paper"
    "react-native-screens"
    "@react-navigation/stack"
    "react-native-reanimated"
    "@react-navigation/drawer"
    "@react-navigation/native"
    "react-native-vector-icons"
    react-native-gesture-handler"
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs"
    "react-native-safe-area-context"
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize"
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core" 
    "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons"
    "@react-native-community/masked-view"
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome"
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs"
```

> So, I used these libraries in my app so wanted to tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that

```
"axios": "*",
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.3",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.2.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-navigation": "4.2.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "5.14.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "9.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "5.11.9",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "*",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons": "*",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "*",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "5.3.15"
```